# How to mount windows partition in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, mount

I have ubuntu 12.10 live CD, when I run this in Disks it shows only one entry of my whole drive (500GB). it's not showing my windows partitions ?

How get all those partitions and mount them ?

Comment: On the left bar (the Launcher), move your mouse to the bottom of it to make it scroll. Do you see a hard disk icon like this: http://i.imgur.com/2tLC02U.png? Or, in Nautilus (or "Files", the file explorer), do you see something under "Devices" like "190GB Volume" like this: http://i.imgur.com/7jD2Ezo.png?

Comment: No, I can't see neither any icon at bottom nor under Devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: All images are for instructional use only**

To automatically mount Windows drives, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo blkid
```

So you can get the UUID of the drive.  Make sure that you get the UUID of the drive with TYPE="ntfs".

[image]

Then edit the fstab config file

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

And add the line at the bottom of the file as shown in the image below.  Make sure to replace the UUID with the UUID of your NTFS drive.  Save and close the file

[image]

Then create mount points, and take ownership by doing:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/Windows
sudo chown -R <username> /media/Windows
```

Comment: and how do I mount it into the current session, without restarting the PC?